# Пытаюсь вывести символы по их ASCII коду, но после 127 выводить какой-то бред, с чем это может быть связано?

Tags: c++, char, ascii

Пытаюсь вывести символы по их ASCII коду, но после 127 выводить какой-то бред, с чем это может быть связано?

ubuntu 14.04 64 bit Geany

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for(int i = 32; i < 256; ++i)
        cout << (char)i << " - " << i << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А у вас консоль в какой кодировке ? Только не говорите, что UTF8, где все символы >127 двухбайтные и должны быть правильно закодированы

Answer (score 1):

Под ubuntu таблица символов по умолчанию utf8. В ней символы старше 127 должны быть как минимум двухбайтные.